# How to round up numpy array to 1dp

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I currently have a pandas dataframe and i got the unique values from a column called `bathrooms`. It looks like this.

```py
king.bathrooms.unique()
>>> array([1.  , 2.25, 3.  , 2.  , 4.5 , 1.5 , 2.5 , 1.75, 2.75, 3.25, 4.  ,
       3.5 , 0.75, 4.75, 5.  , 4.25, 3.75, 0.  , 1.25, 5.25, 6.  , 0.5 ,
       5.5 , 6.75, 5.75, 8.  , 7.5 , 7.75, 6.25, 6.5 ])
```

So what i wanted to do is that i want to round up all elements to 1d.p.

Meaning my expected output is supposed to be something like:

```py
>>>array([1.  , 2.3, 3.  , 2.  , 4.5 , 1.5 , 2.5 , 1.8, 2.8, 3.3, 4.  ,
       3.5 , 0.8, 4.8, 5.  , 4.3, 3.8, 0.  , 1.3, 5.3, 6.  , 0.5 ,
       5.5 , 6.8, 5.8, 8.  , 7.5 , 7.8, 6.3, 6.5 ])
```

I tried doing this currently, but it gives me a `TypeError: return arrays must be of ArrayType`
Here's my current code:

```py
king.bathrooms = np.ceil(king['bathrooms'], 1)
print(king.bathrooms)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think numpy has this builtin (ceil till a decimal place)

You can always multiply all by 10, then ceil and then divide all by 10

`numpyArray = np.ceil(numpyArray*10)/10`

Comment: Yep it worked! Just hope that numpy has it one day. That will make life easier.